# Can I move a VirtualBox vdi from Windows to OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 machine with VirtualBox 4+ installed. It runs a couple of virtual machines (Windows XP, Ubuntu, ...) and some of them have a few shared drives (No two machines with shared drives run at the same time for obvious reasons)

Is it possible to move the vdi files from the Windows 7 host to an OS X host (provided it has the same version of VirtualBox) without any extra measures? Or are there any caveats or gotcha's to this? I ask this question because I don't wanna mess up the virtual machines in the process (either way, I'll clone them before just to be safe...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, and this is one of the biggest benefits of virtualisation.

Only problem may be if your hardware is significantly different (Such as moving from AMD to Intel). In this situation, you may not be able to import snapshots (that are in paused states), but, you should still be able to import the virtual machines.